# Fixing component height, not working (Android app)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I would like to have someone else take a look at the few lines of kotlin code below and point out any error I may have been missing.
I have use similar code before to fix the height of a component to 100, and it has always worked as far as I am aware of.

```
constraintLayout?.addView(component)
val constrSet = ConstraintSet()
constrSet.clone(constraintLayout)
constrSet.connect(component.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                  component.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
constrSet.setMargin(component.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, -100)
constrSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

The problem is that I now have a case where it no longer works. The height goes down to the bottom of the display.
So something must be missing in the code or some arbitrary (hidden) assumption must be made for this code to properly function. Explaining that it doesn't always work. And this is precisely what I am missing.

I hope somebody can figure out some cases where it will not work and so help me solve this issue.

Comment: If you want this to be a fixed height of 100, why not just set its height to 100 using layout prams?  This has never been the right way to set a fixed height for a view

Comment: I tried component.layoutParams.height = 100, but it does not seem to be working any better.

Comment: OK, I tried something with no success. How would you write the code?

Comment: Whatever value I set instead of 100 does not actually seem to make any difference.

Comment: What else did you do with the remainder of your old code?  Because that constraint set makes no sense.  You can't constain the bottom of a view to its own top.  And negative margins aren't generally supported, although LinearLayout supports them for legacy reasons (they were originally not meant to work, accidentaly did, and enough people used them google decided not to fix the bug).  In fact you have no legit constraints on the view at all, which means constraint layout is just guessing at everything.

Comment: Well you're most probably right thinking what I did was not the right way to go, nevertheless this set of constrains with the negative margins is perfectly working, at least is some cases. Beside I found what was my problem: I was not following the correct order for layout.addView(..), constrSet.clone(..), compo.layoutParams.height = ... Now it finally works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For future reference, negative margins are supported if you are using _ConstraintLayout_ 2.1.0-alpha2 or later. See the [release notes](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/constraintlayout-210-alpha-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in comments, set height via layoutParams:

```
 component.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
     ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
     100
 ).apply {
     topToTop = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID         // to place it in the center 
     bottomToBottom = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID   // of the viewgroup
 }
```